# Windows Azure newbie questions and concerns

Tags: azure

So I'm considering using an Azure VM to work with a consulting firm that is working on an application for me and have some basic security questions before going much further. I've been watching some tutorial videos on azure, but still not sure about security and access in general.

How is access to a VM on Azure controlled?  Windows Authentication, https ?
I've seen examples of connecting to a SQL Azure instance with SSMS, how is that secured?

I think I still need to read more...

The target for production is our own server, but we want to use Azure so that the consulting firm can have a development build target that we can see the published changes on.

If we do this, will the code have to change much to be deployed on one of our own servers outside of the Azure environment?

[update]
I think I found most of my questions discussed here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/trust-center/security/

Answer (score 0):

this is a so general question, with Azure, you have a lot of options to publish your applications depends of what application type you have (web, mobile, services, bd), but in generally, you have Azure Web Apps (for web), Cloud Services (for services, web and background process), Mobile Apps (backend for mobile applications), sql database, or use a VM and install all that you need (I put only a few options here).
Next, about security depends what your need, if you created a VM, the VM your, you can access to it using rdp (windows) ir ssh (linux), you can admin all about the vm (users, roles, ports, etc)

When you use SQL Database, you can only gain access base on ip, or using azure active directory, you can configure it!